# Bind project with external dependencies in ObjectiveC to Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding

I'm binding a project, the ApiDefinitions looks like that:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "BEMCheckBox.h"

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

    @interface paintController : UIViewController

    - (BEMCheckBox *)paint;

    @end

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

I'm doing this in sharpie (last version):

```
sharpie bind --sdk=iphoneos12.1 --scope myexample.framework/Headers/ myexample.framework/Headers/PaintControllerExample.h
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
fatal error: 'BEMCheckBox.h' file not found
#import "BEMCheckBox.h"
```

I've tried all the combinations in the import, but still can't do the binding. Can i bind an external library like BEMCheckBox in this case?

Comment: You are scoping the includes/imports to `myexample.framework/Headers/`, is there a `BEMCheckBox.h` header in that dir? If not, where is it..?

Comment: Only have the myexample.framework, and is not there, the original project has the BEMCheckBox into Pods/BEMChechBox/Classes/BEMChechBox

Comment: `BEMChechBox` is a "pod" and thus standalone, if you goal is to use BEMChechBox in your Xamarin/C# iOS app, just bind it (you can try to the `pod` option in Sharpie, sometimes it works, sometimes not...if not, just bind it as a static lib)